# GraphicsMagick Webcam with stamp and private area

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I used the following code to process a webcam-picture (in.jpg), unsharp some area (defined in grayscale-file unsharpmask.png) and add a stamp.

- load in.jpg
- blur this file
- load in.jpg as seperate layer
- apply transparency mask
- compose
- add stamp
- compose again and write to out.jpg

I used the following command to do this with ImageMagick:

> convert in.jpg -blur 0x8 -compose over in.jpg unsharpmask.png -composite -compose over stamp.png -gravity SouthWest -composite -quality 90 out.jpg

But on GraphicsMagick it fails as the "-composite" option is missing,..

How can I do that with GraphicsMagick?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How complicated are your "private" areas and I assume they are always in the same place?

Can you use regions in graphicsmagick and try bluring those areas?

This is some code that will change a specified area to greyscale and I assume you could blur that area by replacing -colorspace Gray with -blur 15 or similar.

```
<?php  
$cmd = "$input -region 140x120+50+20 -colorspace Gray";  
exec("convert $cmd region_gray.jpg"); 
?>
```